# How to customize flask error： Missing required parameter in the JSON body or the post body or the query string

Tags: json, flask, flask-restful, flask-restplus

How to customize flask error：
`Missing required parameter in the JSON body or the post body or the query string`

I need to return a json format response like this:

```
{
  'Error': '{} is Missing',
  'Code': 10000,
  'xxxx.': "xxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are sharing is all about request fields. The response should work as the JSON format is valid.